# sicstus prolog: append string to a variable's value to create a new variable

Tags: string, variables, prolog

I was wondering if there's any way to append a string value to a variable's value to create a new variable.
What I'm thinking:

```
V = 7,
foo(V) :- 
    NV = 'S'+V.
```

So I want NV to have the S7 value in the end, and S7 is a new variable. (V being assigned with value 7 somewhere earlier).

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses an *atom* rather than a *string*. An atom is either an unquoted *bareword*  or a *quoted word*, delimited with apostrophes (`'`). For example:

- `foo` is an atom.
- `'This is a quoted atom'` is also an atom

Other types of atoms include integers (`1234`) and the empty list `[]`. The defining characteristic of an atom is that it is *atomic* (indivisible).

A prolog *string*, on the other hand, is **always** delimited with double quotes (`"`) and is shorthand for a list of characters (integer code points). Some examples:

- `""` is exactly the same as the empty list `[]` (which happens to be an atom).
- `"abc"` is exactly the same thing as the list `[97,98,99]`.

So you should be clear about whether you mean to use *atom* or *string*.

Assuming from your example that you're talking about atoms...

In both Sicstus and SWI prolog you should be able to use `name/2`. For your particular example, you should be able to simply say:

```
foo( X , Y ) :-
  name( 'S' , [S] ) ,
  name( X , Codes ) ,
  name( Y , [S|Codes] )
  .
```

More generally, you should be able to say:

```
foo( AtomicPrefix , NumericSuffix , Concatenation ) :-
  name( AtomicPrefix  , Pfx   ) ,
  name( NumericSuffix , Sfx   ) ,
  append( Pfx , Sfx   , Codes ) ,
  name( Concatenation , Codes )
  .
```

However, `name/2` is not ISO-compliant. Instead, you can use `atom_chars/2` and `number_chars/2` in a similar manner:

```
foo( X, Y ) :-
  number_chars(X,Xs) ,
  atom_chars(Y,['S'|Xs])
  .
```

or, more generally,

```
foo( AtomicPrefix , NumericSuffix , Concatenation ) :-
  atom_chars( AtomicPrefix  , Pfx   ) ,
  number_chars( NumericSuffix , Sfx   ) ,
  append( Pfx , Sfx   , Chars ) ,
  atom_chars( Concatenation , Chars )
  .
```

Or you should be able to use `atom_concat\3` along these lines:

```
foo( Atom , Number , Concatenation ) :-
  number_chars( Number, Ds ) ,
  atom_chars( Sfx , Ds ) ,
  atom_concat( Pfx , Sfx , Concatenation )
  .
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SICStus Prolog, but this works in SWI-Prolog 6.2.6, B-Prolog 8.1 and ECLiPSe CLP Prolog (after loading `lib(iso_light)`):

```
V = 7, number_chars(V, N), atom_chars('S', A), append(A, N, X), atom_chars(NW, X).
```

It may work as is in SICStus, or may require very small modifications.

You may also try `atom_concat/3`, but while some Prolog systems can convert a number to atom automatically, others don't.

This works in SWI-Prolog, but not in B-Prolog or ECLiPSe CLP:

```
V = 7, atom_concat('S', V, NW).
```